# how do i create a boolean to show 24 hour time?

Tags: java, methods, time, return, boolean

Question I have been given

```
public Boolean valid24Time (int hh, int mm2)
```

the hours can only range from 0-23 and the minutes can only be in the range of 0-59

this method must return true if the time is valid and false if invalid

Comment: What language are you using? What have you tried that did not work?

Comment: just java (eclipse) and I can't figure it out at all, I've just started using java.

Comment: Imagine you're in mathematics class, and someone's asked you to write the inequalities for "the hours can only range from 0-23 and the minutes can only be in the range of 0-59" using the usual >, < etc notation. Can you do that?

Comment: yes I can but have no idea when trying to implement into java.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for 'Java if statement', Java also supports the greater than `>` and less than `<` signs. To combine 2 expressions in an if-statement, you can use `&&`.

I think you'll need to be able to figure it out this way.

Comment: I'm working with an if statement and greater than and less currently, still can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is the validation in java:

```
return hh >= 0 && hh <=23 && mm2 >= 0 && mm2 <= 59;
```

Comment: Thank you, I will have a go with this